# Make large size be selected by default in media upload window - Wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, upload, media

In the Add Media window on post edit page, when uploading an image, there are 4 sizes available: `Thumbnail`, `Medium`, `Large` and `Full Size`. The `Full Size` option is selected by default.

How can I make the `Large` option be selected by default instead of `Full Size`?

I would presume that this is possible by adding a PHP code in the functions file?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52088/setting-default-image-size

Comment: @Kemal that question is for creating a custom image size. My question is, how can you make the **Large** size be selected by default on upload media page. Currently, **Full Size** is selected by default.

Comment: My bad, please take a look at my answer.

Comment: is there any improvement on this? This should have been a core feature imho.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer from this post:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66057/adding-a-custom-image-upload-size-and-making-it-selected-by-default

```
function my_default_image_size () {
    return 'large'; 
}

add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'my_default_image_size' );
```

*I tested this on 3.7.1 and it works.*

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's a row in the `options` table in the database in which the value of the `option_name` field is `image_default_size`. If you set the `option_value` field of this row to `large`, then the default option will be the large size instead of the full size (if large is available for the image).

```
UPDATE `database_name`.`prefix_options` SET `option_value` = 'large' WHERE  `prefix_options`.`option_name` = 'image_default_size';
```